# Django template bracket notation with variable key does not work

Tags: django, html-table

I am trying to dynamically render a table based on a table model and it's columns. In the template, I loop over each item in the query set and then over each column from a list of hard coded column names, but Django returns a `Could not parse the remainder: '[column]' from 'table[column]'` error. `table.id` renders the correct id value but `table[column[0]]` returns an error. Does Django not allow bracket notation fro variables?

In this example table is a dict of a model class and columns is a list of the model's column names.

```
        <tbody>
            {% for table in query_set %}
            <tr>
                {% for column in columns %}
                    <td>{{table[column]}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

I have also tried using the .items method on the table dict:

```
        <tbody>
            {% for table in query_set %}
            <tr>
                {% for key, value in table.items %}
                    <td>{{value}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

but this renders nothing. table.items seems to be undefined.

The corresponding view:

```
def index(request):
    cur_user = request.user
    Model = get_model(query.table)
    columns = get_table_columns(query.table)

    #
    # code for processing raw SQL query here
    #

    query_set = Model.objects.raw(query_string)

    context = {
        'columns': columns,
        'cur_user': cur_user,
        'query_set': query_set
    }
    return render(request, 'flight_deck/index.html', context)
```

Comment: share the corresponding view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I update with the view. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's template language does *not* support subscripting (i.e. `x[y]`), this has been done deliberately to prevent people from writing *business logic* in the templates. One can use [*Jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/) as a template language, but this is not necessary and to some extent counterproductive, precisely to prevent writing business logic in the template.

It thus makes more sense to "prepare" the data to pass it in a more accessible format to the template, like:

```
def index(request):
    Model = get_model(query.table)
    columns = get_table_columns(query.table)

    #
    # code for processing raw SQL query here
    #

    queryset = Model.objects.raw(query_string)
    data = [[getattr(row, column) for column in columns] for row in queryset]

    context = {'columns': columns, 'data': data}
    return render(request, 'flight_deck/index.html', context)
```

and render this with:

```
{% for row in data %}
<tr>
    {% for cell in row %}
        <td>{{ cell }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: There is no need to pass the current user into the template, if you use [**`render(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) with a set request, the request is accessible in the template, so you can use `{{ request.user }}`.

---

> **Note**: Using raw queries is often not a good idea: one has to be careful about SQL injection but likely more important: it does not allow further post-processing of the queryset like ordering, paginating, etc. at the database level.

Comment: This solution works. Thanks! To address the notes, I removed the user object from the context and accessed it directly in the template. As for the raw queries, I am aware of the dangers of raw SQL queries due to injection but this is not a public application and I am handling ordering and pagination manually on the backend. Thanks for the advice!